# renaming of columns in pandas using other data frame

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have data frame with 4 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1., 2., 3., 4.],
    'two': [4., 3., 2., 1.],
    'three': [4., 3., 2., 1.],
    'four': [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
```

and suppose there is another data frame(2 columns):
The first column consists of names of the columns of data frame `df`('one','two','three','four') and next column consists of names, to which I want to change column names of the `df` data frame.

How can I do it in pandas in one/two line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `rename` by `dict` or by `Series`:

```
print (df1)
       a  b
0    one  c
1    two  d
2  three  e
3   four  f

d = df1.set_index('a')['b'].to_dict()
#by Series
#d = df1.set_index('a')['b']
print (d)
{'four': 'f', 'two': 'd', 'three': 'e', 'one': 'c'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1., 2., 3., 4.],
    'two': [4., 3., 2., 1.],
    'three': [4., 3., 2., 1.],
    'four': [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
print (df)

df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df)
     f    c    e    d
0  4.0  1.0  4.0  4.0
1  3.0  2.0  3.0  3.0
2  2.0  3.0  2.0  2.0
3  1.0  4.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Glad can help! You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.